# What is an "actuation state"

Tags: kinematics, navigation, actuator

The paper *A Feedforward Control Approach to the Local Navigation Problem for Autonomous Vehicles* by Alonzo Kelly uses the term **actuation space**.

> Feedforward solves the historically significant clothoid generation problem trivially. C space combinatoric explosion is solved by planning in **actuation space**.

I have attempted to search for this term via Google. However, I can only find applications of actuation spaces—not what an actual space actually *is*.

A definition or source for further investigation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after reading this ... there are mentions of task-space, state-space, configuration-space, etc

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282198949_Fuzzy_logic_control_of_a_continuum_manipulator_for_surgical_applications

then this link ...

https://helgewurdemann.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/embc-2015-embedded-electro-conductive-yarn-for-shape-sensing-of-soft-manipulators-wurdemann-sareh-shafti-noh-faragasso-chathuranga-liu-hirai-althoefer.pdf

contains this text ...

> As explained in the previous section, the shape sensing system
>   consists of a set of three electro-conductive yarn threads with the
>   resistances [R1(s1), R2(s2), R3(s3)]. As a linear function can be
>   defined describing the relation between the resistance and the length
>   of the yarn thread within the elongation interval [0;156%], it is
>   possible to continuously calculate and update the length of the three
>   threads [s1, s2, s3]. These actuation space variables are now used to
>   obtain the arc parameters as shown in Figure 5 and Equations 1-3 [16].

I may very well be wrong about this, but to me it implies that "actuation space" is collection of entities or variables that relate to the physical world in which the robot operates and includes the robot itself. (there is probably a better way to word it though)